# Firebase android оптимизация получения данных

Tags: java, android, firebase

В процессе выполнения метода требуется получить 2 выборки данных из одной и той же ветки. Затем скоректировать значения и записать обратно. Как правильно организовать этот метод?
Сделал при помощи вложенных в друг друга слушателей. Может есть более правильный подход?
И как сделать, чтобы этот метод возвращал результат (к примеру boolean) при успешном выполнении команды записи в Firebase?

Код работы метода:

```
public static void UpdateBalancesInFB (final long DateMove, final double DeltaValue, DatabaseReference FBRef){
        //TODO: как получить успешное выполнение метода?!
        final DatabaseReference mDBref = FBRef.child(MyTypesAndUtils.sFB_Balances);
        final boolean result = false;

        /*получаем с Firebase выгрузку последней записи и данных следующих за Date_min */
        final Query mQuery = mDBref.orderByKey();
        mQuery.limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final long[] Date_last = {DateMove};
                final double[] Value_last = {DeltaValue};

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Date_last[0] = Long.valueOf(snapshot.getKey());
                    Value_last[0] = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
                }
                mQuery.startAt(String.valueOf(DateMove)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        boolean mark = false;
                        Map<String, Object> mQueryBalances = new HashMap<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            mQueryBalances.put(snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue());
                            mark = true;
                        }
                        /*корректируем значения остатков после даты движения*/
                        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Object> entry : mQueryBalances.entrySet()) {
                            Date_last[0] = Long.valueOf(entry.getKey());
                            Value_last[0] = Double.valueOf(entry.getValue().toString()) + DeltaValue;
                            mQueryBalances.put(entry.getKey(), Value_last[0]);
                        }

                        /*дополняем коллекцию недостающими элементами до даты движения и 1 элемент после нее*/
                        //это возможно только если mQueryBalances пустой
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(Date_last[0]);         //последняя запись остатков
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);         //переводим на 1й день месяца (на всякий случай)

                        while (!mark) {                                 // это возможно только если mQueryBalances пустой
                            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                            Date_last[0] = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                            if (Date_last[0] <= DateMove)
                                mQueryBalances.put(String.valueOf(Date_last[0]), Value_last[0]);
                            else{
                                mQueryBalances.put(String.valueOf(Date_last[0]), Value_last[0]+DeltaValue);
                                mark = true;
                            }
                        }

                        /*Записываем в Firebase*/
                        mDBref.updateChildren(mQueryBalances, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                //result = true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Код вызова этого метода тоже выполняется внутри слушателя:

```
myRef.child(MyTypesAndUtils.sFB_Movements).child(mMove_output.getKeyFB()).setValue(mMove_output).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                long Date2, Date1;
                double Value2, Value1;

                Date2 = mMove_output.getDateInMilisec();
                Value2 = mMove_output.getValue()*mMove_output.getKind();
                if (mMove_input != null) {
                    Date1 = mMove_input.getDateInMilisec();
                    Value1 = mMove_input.getValue()*mMove_input.getKind();
                    if (Date2==Date1)
                        MyTypesAndUtils.UpdateBalancesInFB(Date2, (Value2-Value1), myRef);
                    else {
                        MyTypesAndUtils.UpdateBalancesInFB(Date1, (-Value1), myRef);
                        MyTypesAndUtils.UpdateBalancesInFB(Date2, Value2, myRef);
                    }
                }
                else    MyTypesAndUtils.UpdateBalancesInFB(Date2, (Value2), myRef);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Сохранение произошло", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //TODO: переписать в string
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Кажется что как раз тот случай когда на клиенте не стоит делать сложную бизнес-логику, я бы вынес ее на сторону Functions + сделал асинхронную обработку запроса.

Comment: что значит на сторону Functions?

Comment: Вообще да, эта логика абсолютна не нужна на клиенте, т.к. не требует никакого участия пользователя....

Comment: А в какой среде разработки пишут под Node.js? не в блокноте же? в первые сталкиваюсь с javascript...